# Can't update from OSX 10.9.5 to OSX Yosemite 10.10

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I bought my 13 inch non-retina MacBook Pro on December 2013. It's got...

4 GB of 1600 MHz DDR3 SDRAM

500 GB 5400-rpm hard drive

To update to OSX Yosemite 10.10 takes 5.64 GB. So does it mean I CAN'T update from 10.9.5 to 10.10 OSX Yosemite with my MacBook Pro?

Comment: Why not, it only takes about 5 Gig and you have 500 Gig (or less)

Comment: Maybe because I have 4GB and it takes 5.64, then I can't update or it has nothing to do with the 4GB part?

Comment: Every computer has two types of memory (storage space). The Hard drive or the newer SSD type, they are also called the permanent memory. Stuff on it stays saved when you turn off the computer. The other storage is RAM, also known as dynamic memory. It is only used while computer is running, to speed things up. The RAM is not permanent and gets erased each time you turn off the computer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misreading the numbers.

Yosemite takes a little more than 5 Gig.

Your Hard drive is 500 Gig. Even if you have used (consumed) lots of it, if you still have about 10 Gig of free space you can upgrade to Yosemite.

To look how much space you have on your Hard drive:

Click on the top left Apple symbol and then on the About this Mac.

In the new window click on "More Info", now click on the Storage Tab.

It looks like this on my Mac, showing I have 108 Gig free.

[image: storage]

The other storage is called RAM (that is not your hard disk). Yosemite needs minimum 2 Gig and you have 4 Gig, so no problem there.

Answer (score 0):

You have 4GB of RAM. RAM however in this case doesn't impact whether or not you can upgrade an OS. That 5G of space is hard drive space, not RAM. Since you have 100 times that on your hard drive, you should have plenty of room.

Comment: "RAM however doesn't impact whether or not you can upgrade an OS." Not necessarily true. In this case, it is true, but see e.g. the jump from 1GB required in 10.6.x to 2GB required in 10.7.x. Even beyond absolute requirements, though, is practical requirements. Yosemite only requires 2GB but I sure as hell wouldn't want to try running with that little.

Comment: @tubedogg I meant in this case

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to update and it is not updating, you can always create a bootable USB drive with the installer of OS X 10.10.x, boot your system using alt key, choose to boot from the previously made USB drive and just say upgrade or open Disk Utilities, erase your drive and reinstall a fresh copy of your operating system.
But be sure to backup all your data before proceeding.

To create a bootable USB drive for your installer just search for creating bootable usb for Yosemite installer.